Map an address to itself in protected mode?
I'm experimenting with Linux kernel, trying to reduce its codebase to a minimal "hello, world" that is made of as few files as possible, so that I can get a good understanding of its build and boot process. Today I managed to write the following function that works in my VM (pull request):
static void write_to_vga(void)
{
    volatile unsigned short *vga_buffer = (volatile unsigned short *)ioremap(0xb8000, 4096);
    vga_buffer[0] = 0x073F;
    vga_buffer[1] = 0x073F;

    for(;;);
}

Problem is that it relies on ioremap, which in turn pulls in page allocator and ideally I'd like write_to_vga to be self contained. I can't replace ioremap with an assignment 0xb8000 and I think it's because I'm in protected mode and this address has to be mapped. What would the assembly look like that would map 0xb8000 to itself, with read/write permissions? I don't mind it breaking Linux's internal state - write_to_vga should never exit.

There are a few concepts to understand before doing things like this. One of them is paging. If you want to map an address, you will have to create adequate page table entries for it. Doing this in ASM is not trivial. Linux itself doesn't do it in ASM. You usually set up paging and then transition to C as soon as you can. I would suggest building your own very basic OS from scratch following the guides in the OSDev wiki, not hacking around with Linux code, which is very, very complex.

You don't need the allocator, you just need to make sure the memory is identity mapped. Depending on what you have removed I assume you still have paging enabled and an initial page table set up.

If you're in 32-bit protected mode (not 64-bit long mode), it's possible to disable paging via a bit in a control register.  Then linear addresses are physical, exactly(?) like if you created page tables that identity-map all of virtual address-space.  With a flat memory model (segment bases=0, limit=-1), then 32-bit address you use are physical.  (Before doing that, you need to make sure there's a copy of the GDT and IDT, and the kernel code+data+stack, at the "new" address if they weren't already in identity-mapped pages.)
